# Solve function strange behavior

Tags: equation-solving

there! Can you please answer me the question I'm trying to resolve for an hour? There is a system of two linear equations and the condition, that the solution should be in range [0; 1]. So, when I try that:

```
    Solve[161.355600165021` v^5 + 
        94.1791967439481` (10 v^2 - 30 v^3 + 30 v^4 - 10 v^5) + 
        135.98059711265` (5 v^4 - 5 v^5) + 
        42.0599417466681` (1 - 5 v + 10 v^2 - 10 v^3 + 5 v^4 - v^5) + 
        71.0780007446277` (5 v - 20 v^2 + 30 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 5 v^5) + 
        114.700929086124` (10 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 10 v^5) == 
       56.010658939198926` && -142.175250958881` - 
        59.037829392769936` v + 33.38481164793984` v^2 + 
        28.05246519684033` v^3 + 4.547473508864641`*^-12 v^4 - 
        3.069544618483633`*^-12 v^5 == -147.71713331648178`, v]
```

it gives me the result `{{v -> 0.1}}`. But, when I add the condition, it gives me zero result:

```
Solve[161.355600165021` v^5 + 
    94.1791967439481` (10 v^2 - 30 v^3 + 30 v^4 - 10 v^5) + 
    135.98059711265` (5 v^4 - 5 v^5) + 
    42.0599417466681` (1 - 5 v + 10 v^2 - 10 v^3 + 5 v^4 - v^5) + 
    71.0780007446277` (5 v - 20 v^2 + 30 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 5 v^5) + 
    114.700929086124` (10 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 10 v^5) == 
   56.010658939198926` && -142.175250958881` - 
    59.037829392769936` v + 33.38481164793984` v^2 + 
    28.05246519684033` v^3 + 4.547473508864641`*^-12 v^4 - 
    3.069544618483633`*^-12 v^5 == -147.71713331648178` && (0 <= v <= 
    1), v]
```

Why is it so, and how to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Don't know why it is so, but `Reduce` works.

Answer (score 2):

The two equations don't have a common solution.
One has the root `v -> 0.1000000000000002950999497771515296638`
The other has `v -> 0.09999999999999998355764539790918157`

So whether `0.1` is returned as a solution relies on rounding error, and when you add the interval inequality or swap between `Solve` and `Reduce` the rounding errors that occur are no longer the same.

You could solve each equation separately and use `Intersection` with `SameTest` to decide how close the roots needs to be before they are considered equal:

```
ineq = 0 ≤ v ≤ 1;
eq1 = 161.355600165021` v^5 + 94.1791967439481` (10 v^2 - 30 v^3 + 30 v^4 - 10 v^5) + 135.98059711265` (5 v^4 - 5 v^5) + 42.0599417466681` (1 - 5 v + 10 v^2 - 10 v^3 + 5 v^4 - v^5) + 71.0780007446277` (5 v - 20 v^2 + 30 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 5 v^5) + 114.700929086124` (10 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 10 v^5) == 56.010658939198926`;
eq2 = -142.175250958881` - 59.037829392769936` v + 33.38481164793984` v^2 + 28.05246519684033` v^3 + 4.547473508864641`*^-12 v^4 - 3.069544618483633`*^-12 v^5 == -147.71713331648178`;

Intersection[##, SameTest -> Equal] & @@ (v /. Solve[#, v] & /@ {eq1, eq2})
Intersection[##, SameTest -> Equal] & @@ (v /. Solve[# && ineq, v] & /@ {eq1, eq2})
(* {0.1} *)
(* {0.1} *)
```

Comment: But, if this two equations don't have the same solution, why does it give the right solution in the first Solve[] example? And how to rewrite the code to obtain the result, without using Reduce[] function?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
eqns = 161.355600165021` v^5 + 
     94.1791967439481` (10 v^2 - 30 v^3 + 30 v^4 - 10 v^5) + 
     135.98059711265` (5 v^4 - 5 v^5) + 
     42.0599417466681` (1 - 5 v + 10 v^2 - 10 v^3 + 5 v^4 - v^5) + 
     71.0780007446277` (5 v - 20 v^2 + 30 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 5 v^5) + 
     114.700929086124` (10 v^3 - 20 v^4 + 10 v^5) == 
    56.010658939198926` && -142.175250958881` - 59.037829392769936` v + 
     33.38481164793984` v^2 + 28.05246519684033` v^3 + 
     4.547473508864641`*^-12 v^4 - 
     3.069544618483633`*^-12 v^5 == -147.71713331648178`;
```

As you indicated, without the constraint `Solve` works

```
Solve[eqns, v]

(* {{v -> 0.1}} *)
```

Whereas, with the constraint

```
Solve[eqns && 0 < v < 1, v]

(* {} *)
```

This is a precision issue. As a workaround, insure that all values have the same fixed precision less than 17

```
Table[
 Solve[(eqns && 0 < v < 1) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // N[#, wp] &, v], 
  {wp, 10, 17}]

(* {{{v -> 0.100000000}}, {{v -> 0.1000000000}}, {{v -> 0.10000000000}}, {{v -> 
    0.100000000000}}, {{v -> 0.1000000000000}}, {{v -> 
    0.10000000000000}}, {{v -> 0.100000000000000}}, {}} *)
```

Alternatively, treat as a minimization problem

```
Minimize[{Total[(Subtract @@@ (List @@ eqns))^2], 0 < v < 1}, v]

(* {2.58763*10^-28, {v -> 0.1}} *)
```